# Adding a simple Javascript file with a plugin

Tags: plugins, php, javascript

I just want to create an alert box when a page with a post is reloaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.alert("alert");
</script>
```

And here is the php code i wrote to load the js.

```
function alert_js(){
   wp_enqueue_script('alert_js', plugins_url( '/alert.js', __FILE__ ));
}
add_action('the_post', 'alert_js');
```

I'm sure that it successfully finds the script in right place(I checked the page source.). But somehow it acts like there is no javascript included. What I'm missing there?

Comment: This is more of a question, then an answer, however… Do you have script tags in your JavaScript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the trigger... your javascript should be something like this in order for it to trigger when the page is loaded:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: Also, you should use `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook to load stylesheets and scripts as best practice. Mark this answer as best answer if solved your problem.